# How to convert curl request to JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, curl

I've never worked with curl commands, and I've got some task with a line of API request.
Anyone can help me convert it into jquery?
that request for top trending repos created last week

```
curl -G https://api.github.com/search/repositories --data-urlencode ";q=created:>;`date -v-1w '+%Y-%m-%d'`"; --data-urlencode ";sort=stars"; --data-urlencode ";order=desc"; -H ";Accept: application/json";
```

Comment: you could look at the fetch api https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch or jquery ajax http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function to create the URI needed for your JSON request:

```
const listReposURI = date => {
  const baseURI = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories";
  const dateStr = `${date.getFullYear()}-${date.getMonth() + 1}-${date.getDate()}`;

  return `${baseURI}?q=created=${dateStr}&sort=stars&order=desc`
};

//

const now = new Date();
const lastWeek = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate() - 7);

console.log(listReposURI(lastWeek))
```